# Separate enum into 2 different hash maps

Tags: java, enums

I have a `Type` enum that differentiates between the type of web and mobile:

```
WEB_TYPE1("T1", "Web Type 1"),
WEB_TYPE2("T2", "Web Type 2"),
MOBILE_TYPE1("T3", "Mobile Type 1"),
MOBILE_TYPE2("T4", "Mobile Type 2");
```

I want to separate both in to 2 different HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> webMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> mobileMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I am able to loop through the entire enum and put it in 1 map, but not able to separate it out, how should i separate it into 2 different map? I wonder if i do like:

```
WEB_TYPE1("T1", "Web Type 1", **"web"**),
WEB_TYPE2("T2", "Web Type 2", **"web"**),
MOBILE_TYPE1("T3", "Mobile Type 1", **"mobile"**),
MOBILE_TYPE2("T4", "Mobile Type 2", "mobile");
```

Comment: I don't get your question. An enum has fixed content, why don't you just create two enum set instances and add those enums to each set that they belong to. There is no point in creating maps with data that you somehow put into an enum constant.

Comment: What do you mean by "Separate it into 2 different map"? Can you give an example? As it stands, your question does not make sense.

Comment: Addendum: it seems wrong that you use enums... That are based on strings. Why not used some inner enum. You could have an outer type enum, and then further refining enums inside of that thing.

Comment: @GhostCat inner enum, never think of that, i will have a look with inner enum, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I don't have a clear idea how to go about it. The point is simply that it doesn't make to much sense to mix true enum constant with something that relies on string "constants". Imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do this:

1.- Create your enum
2.- Iterate your enum and do a validation using startswith or a regex (in my case i used startsWith)
3.- Once you have the answer add to your hashMap
4.- look at this

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

enum Type {
     WEB_TYPE1("T1", "Web Type 1"),
     WEB_TYPE2("T2", "Web Type 2"),
     MOBILE_TYPE1("T3", "Mobile Type 1"),
     MOBILE_TYPE2("T4", "Mobile Type 2");

    private String type;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    private String name;


    Type(String type,String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
public class SeparateHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> webMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> mobileMap = new HashMap<>();
          for (Type status : Type.values()) {
                System.out.println(status);
                if(status.toString().startsWith("WEB_")){
                    webMap.put(status.toString(), status.getName());
                }else{
                    mobileMap.put(status.toString(), status.getName());
                }
            }




Map<String, String> map = webMap;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "   " + entry.getValue());
}

Map<String, String> map2 = mobileMap;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map2.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "    " + entry.getValue());
}


    }

}
```

it will give you this:

```
WEB_TYPE1
WEB_TYPE2
MOBILE_TYPE1
MOBILE_TYPE2
WEB_TYPE2   Web Type 2
WEB_TYPE1   Web Type 1
MOBILE_TYPE2    Mobile Type 2
MOBILE_TYPE1    Mobile Type 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public enum Type {
    WEB_TYPE1("T1", "Web Type 1"),
    WEB_TYPE2("T2", "Web Type 2"),
    MOBILE_TYPE1("T3", "Mobile Type 1"),
    MOBILE_TYPE2("T4", "Mobile Type 2");

    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    Type(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }    
}

public class EnumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> webMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> mobileMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Type t : Type.values()) {
            if (t.getB().contains("Web")) {
                webMap.put(t.getA(), t.getB());
            } else if (t.getB().contains("Mobile")) {
                mobileMap.put(t.getA(), t.getB());
            } 

        }

        for (String s : webMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", s, webMap.get(s));
        }

        for (String s : mobileMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", s, mobileMap.get(s));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I was writing my post.

Answer (score 1):

Why not encapsulate the web and mobile as enum types, then you are free to create multiple variations of those types within your `Type` enum?

For example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;

public class EnumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Type.WEB_MAP);
        System.out.println(Type.MOBILE_MAP);
    }

    enum DeviceType {
        WEB,
        MOBILE;
    }

    enum Type {
        T1(DeviceType.WEB, "Web Type 1"),
        T2(DeviceType.WEB, "Web Type 2"),
        T3(DeviceType.MOBILE, "Mobile Type 1"),
        T4(DeviceType.MOBILE, "Mobile Type 2");

        public final DeviceType devType;
        public final String description;

        public static final Map<Type, String> WEB_MAP;
        public static final Map<Type, String> MOBILE_MAP;

        Type(DeviceType devType, String description) {
            this.devType = devType;
            this.description = description;
        }

        static {
            Map<Type, String> web = new HashMap<>();
            Map<Type, String> mob = new HashMap<>();

            for (Type t : Type.values()) {
                switch (t.devType) {
                    case WEB:
                        web.put(t, t.description);
                        break;
                    case MOBILE:
                        mob.put(t, t.description);
                        break;
                }
            }

            WEB_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(web);
            MOBILE_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mob);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
{T1=Web Type 1, T2=Web Type 2}
{T3=Mobile Type 1, T4=Mobile Type 2}
```